# Getting started with Apache PIG, need help on script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, data-science

I started using Pig yesterday for a job opportunity, I never used it before and have to produce something for next week. I still haven't managed to install it but working on it ...

In the mean time, I tried to learn to use Pig Latin, and I produced something, but I can't test it.

The data I'm working from is of the form
    user_name|Country|movie|director
and each time the user watches a movie, a new entry gets in the file, and a file represents 1 day.

What I want to do is to create a "user profile" stating the the top5 movies for the user, the top5 directors, and how many movies the user watches per day.

What I coded :

```
daily_watch=LOAD '$docs_in' USING PigStorage('|') AS     (user_id:int,country:chararray,director_id:int,movie_id:int)

users=GROUP daily_watch BY (user_id);
number_of_watch= FOREACH users GENERATE group, COUNT(daily_watch) AS total; 
STORE number_of_watch INTO "$number_of_watch"
--at this point I want number of watch = (user_id,number_film_watched)


directors_and_users =  GROUP daily_watch BY (user_id,director_id);
top_directors= FOREACH directors_and_users GENERATE 
    user_id
    group
    COUNT(daily_watch) AS total_director;
top5_directors= FOREACH top_directors {
    sorted = order directors_and_users by total_directors desc;
    top5= limit sorted 5;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(top5);
};
STORE top_director INTO "$top5_directors"
--at this point I want top5_directors=(user_id,{user_id,director_id},number_of_movie_seen_from_director)


movies_directors_users= GROUP daily_watch BY (user_id,movie_id,director_id);
top_movies = FOREACH movies_directors_users GENERATE
    user_id
    group
    COUNT(daily_watch) AS total_movies
;
top5_movies= FOREACH top_movies {
    sorted=order movies_directors_users by total_movies desc;
    top5=limit sorted 5;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(top5);
}
--at this point, I want top5_movies=(user_id,{user_id,director_id,movie_id},number_of_times_movie_seen)


STORE top5_movies INTO "$top5_movies"
output= FOREACH users GENERATE AppendToBag(top5_movies.$1,top5_movies.$2,top5_directors.$1,top5_directors.$2)
-- now I want to have output=(user_id,{user_id,director_id,movie_id},number_of_times_movie_seen,{user_id,director_id},number_of_movie_seen_from_director)
```

Is there any obvious mistake in my code ? Am i on the good way ? I am trying to embed  this code in python (I have written the python part).

Also, is there an easy way to test my code ? (I have written some txt files to test with, but I'm having a hard time installing hadoop and pig on my pc (I have windows 7).

Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloudera-Live](http://www.cloudera.com/get-started/cloudera-live.html) which comes with a light weight VM. This comes with [Cloudera Hue](http://gethue.com/), A Django based web tool, which comes with a Pig editor, which you can use for testing and runs. Happy scripting!

Answer (score 0):

To count items by id, I recommend you to use DATAFU, very powerful.
http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/bag-operations.html
It comes with bag operation, so you can count, avg, sum, and quantile in bags.